# Using Material UI for React on Rails 7

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, material-ui, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm currently toying around with react on rails "the proper way", AKA using import maps [as exemplified by DHH](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k73LKxim6tw). Instead of creating everything by myself, I want to use material's components.

So, I have run `./bin/importmap pin react react-dom htm` and my `importmaps.rb` file looked like:

```
#standard stuff, turbo rails etc.
...
pin_all_from "app/javascript/components", under: "components"
pin "htm", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:htm@3.1.1/dist/htm.module.js"
pin "react", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:react@18.2.0/index.js"
pin "react-dom", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:react-dom@18.2.0/index.js"
pin "process", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@jspm/core@2.0.0-beta.24/nodelibs/browser/process-production.js"
pin "scheduler", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:scheduler@0.23.0/index.js"
```

under `javascripts/components` I have

```
//htm_create_element.js
import { createElement } from "react"
import htm from "htm"
export default htm.bind(createElement)
```

and

```
//index.js
import { render } from "react-dom"
import h from "components/htm_create_element"

render(
    h`<h1> Hi from HTM</h1>`,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

It was all okay (even with a hand-made clock component) and properly shown. Then, I wanted to start using material components, so I ran `./bin/importmap pin @mui/material` which added about 200 lines to my `importmap.rb` file (does this amount make any sense?). Next, I tried addind an empty `Rating` component, as can be seen [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-rating/#BasicRating.tsx). So now, my `index.js` is

```
import { render } from "react-dom"
import h from "components/htm_create_element"

import Rating from "@mui/material/Rating"


render(
    h`<h1> Hi from HTM</h1> <${Rating} name="no-value" value={null} />`,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

but nothing shows (no component is rendered) and devtools console gives me

> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
> at chainPropTypes (chainPropTypes.js:2:7)
> at elementAcceptingRef.js:47:29

Any ideas on what went wrong?